# Issues with Dropdown button in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having issues getting a Dropdownbutton widget working in flutter (1.0), it is constantly throwing errors,

following is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Myapp());

class Myapp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new Myappstate();
  }
}

class Myappstate extends State<Myapp> {
  String value = '';
  List<String> values = [];
  void init() {
    values.addAll(['one', 'two']);
    value = values.elementAt(0);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("drop down demo"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DropdownButton(
              items: values.map((String val) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: val,
                  child: Text(val),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: null,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I recieve following error :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter ( 4352): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4352): The following assertion was thrown building Myapp(state: Myappstate#1abe5):
I/flutter ( 4352): MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
I/flutter ( 4352): No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().
I/flutter ( 4352): This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce
I/flutter ( 4352): a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.
I/flutter ( 4352): The context used was:
I/flutter ( 4352):   Scaffold(dirty, state: ScaffoldState#cda06(lifecycle state: initialized, tickers: tracking 1
I/flutter ( 4352):   ticker))
```

I am trying to add this very basic widget but for some reason i have not been able to find the problem.

appreaciate any help i can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap in a MaterialApp and load the initial data in initState.

check this code with minor changes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomeapp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomeapp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyHomeappstate();
  }
}

class MyHomeappstate extends State<MyHomeapp> {
  String value = '';
  List<String> values = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      values.addAll(['one', 'two']);
      value = values.elementAt(0);
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("drop down demo"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DropdownButton(
              hint: Container(
                child: Text('Select option'),
              ),
              items: values.map((String val) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: val,
                  child: Text(val),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                debugPrint('selected option: $val');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```